# Need help with solving an algebraic question.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would appreciate some further pointers on how I may simplify this problem so that it is in its simplest form.

$${1\over x^2−4x+3} +  {1\over x^2−5x+6} +  {1\over x^2−3x+2}$$

I have gotten as far to cross multiply everything so that it is all over the same denominator but am unsure of what to do next.

Comment: What do you mean by "solving"? One usually solves an equation, or a problem, but you haven't written an equation, and you haven't presented a problem, just an expression.

Comment: I'm glad you have returned to edit your question, but you have not engaged at all with my comment. An expression isn't a problem. What do you mean by "solve"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{1}{ x^2−4x+3} + \frac{1}{ x^2−5x+6} + \frac {1}{x^2−3x+2}=\frac{1}{ (x-1)(x-3)} + \frac{1}{( x−2)(x-3)} + \frac {1}{(x-2)(x-1)}=\frac {(x-2)+(x-1)+(x-3)}{(x-3)(x-2)(x-1)}=....$